# Clonezilla 500GB to 250GB - Failed to find this partition in this system: /dev/sdb1

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have HDD with three partitions:

Hidden: Asus Recovery Partition ~ 22GB

C: Windows 7 ~ 160GB

D: Some data ~ 260GB

I have new SSD 250GB and what I want is a clone of Hidden partition and C: to my new SSD. D: partition is not important and I dont want it, but it has some important data, so I cant delete it.

I just want to run cloning and it should failed somewhere while cloning D partition and the I would delete D partition (if created) on SSD. Finally all boot information should be cloned and I should run Win7 on my new SSD and be able to use ASUS RECOVERY partition with F8.

I downloaded Clonezilla, run device to device cloning, it warned me about the sizes but let me continue and it fails to clone such disks saying:
Failed to find this partition in this system: /dev/sdb1

Failed to find this partition in this system: /dev/sdb1

Comment: Can you confirm which drive is which? sda is your 250gb SSD and sdb is your 500gb HDD?

Comment: When you use `device-to-device` it thinks you are cloning to a device of the same or larger capacity (most people want to move to a larger disk). You may want to use Windows to resize your C and D partitions so that they fit a total space less than your SSD. You can then use CloneZilla to image your partitions.

Comment: Its not possible to resise partitions on HDD, they are full of data and I want to clone HDD to SSD -just it nothing else. Source is HDD (SDA) 500GB, on SSD (SDB) I have no partitions just unallocated space. I am playing with settigs, in advanced mode and ticked the icds option and unticek r option and then selected use poartition tabel from source disk and now I have ErrorL: Cant have a partition outside the disk!

Comment: Can Clonezilla do such cloning? I also cant clone partitions one by one because then I cant boot to Windows from SSD, I tried it as well as repairing system and recovering MBR, no options are left I think, only Clonezilla or something similar for FREE that would clone WHOLE disk and fail and the end somehow.

Comment: I'd look into creating a VHD from a disk (Sysinternals Disk2VHD) and then using VHD2Disk utility to restore to a different drive. Also, look here: https://orientman.wordpress.com/2012/10/27/moving-windows-7-partition-to-ssd-drive/ . I cant give an answer since I didnt test it, but I hope this helps. If it does, please write down the steps for others that may face similar issue

Comment: Ok i'll write my remarks if I use Desk2VHD but suprisingly Clonezilla is still cloning my drive to smaller SSD after ticking icds, unticking r, forcing byte by byte copy. Lets see what happens next.
If it fails, next solution would be to clone D partition on some other external disk (I have Touro 1TB case). Then I will delete D partition on Seagate 500GB and then I would be able to clone without problems and finally I would recreate D partiion in Seagate from Touro.

Comment: Strange thing happened. Now I have SSD that is not formatted according to Windows (when attached via USB) and without any partitions (in Gparted in Linux) . When I attach it via SATA it boots but Windows restarts during loading, I pushed F8 and started StartupRepair.
 I am starting to clone partition D from HDD, next we will see. What could I do with SSD now ?