# How can I transfer Windows 10 from an HDD to an SSD if the HDD contains two partitions?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, migration

I have a PC with Windows 10 installed. The partition layout is as follows at the moment:

```
Drive Partition   Size        Description
==================================================================
HDD   (sdb)     1000,0  GB    MBR partitioned drive
      C:         460,5  GB    Windows (and some programs)
      Recovery     0,7  GB
      D:         460,5  GB    Several programs

SSD   (sdd)      500,0  GB    (Unformated/unpartitioned SSD)
```

And this is what I want to achieve:

```
Drive Partition   Size        Description
==================================================================
HDD   (sdb)     1000,0  GB    MBR partitioned drive (with a single partition)
      D:         980,0  GB    (former D: on HDD extended to full drive)

SSD   (sdd)      500,0  GB    MBR partitioned drive (with a single bootable partition)
      C:         460,5  GB    Windows (and some programs)  (former C: on HDD)
```

I tried to clone `C:` to the SSD with `ntfsclone` (roughly `ntfsclone -O /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdb1`), but Windows still boots from the HDD, not from the SSD.

Unfortunately, some startup programs are installed on `D:`, not on `C:`. Therefore, I need to make sure that:

1. C: lands on the SSD (e.g. with `ntfsclone -O /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdb1`),
2. Windows boots from the SSD (no idea here, MB boot manager should use the SSD, but doesn't), and
3. Windows recognizes the D: partition correctly.

How can I simultaneously migrate the primary boot partition from a HDD to a SSD as well as extend the other partition to the whole HDD?

Note that I don't want a full disk-to-disk clone. In case that makes any difference, I have both grml and Clonezilla at hand.

Comment: Related, but not the same question: https://superuser.com/questions/1017583/clonezilla-500gb-to-250gb-failed-to-find-this-partition-in-this-system-dev-s

Comment: Does the disk use GPT or MBR partitioning scheme?

Comment: @gronostaj MBR as far as I know, there is also no 100MB FAT UEFI partition at the HDD's start. I'll recheck in 15 minutes. (I've tried to `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd bs=512 count=8` already).

Comment: That would be rather unusual, as EFI partition would be obsolete on an MBR disk. Please check it.

Comment: @gronostaj I said "there is also ***no*** ... UEFI partition". Either way, it's MBR (see last edit).

Comment: Windows natively supports partition imaging via `DISM /Capture-Image /?` and `DISM /Apply-Image /?`, of which **does not** create configuration issues.  To rebuild a boot partition on a BIOS motherboard and correct boot related issues, boot to WinPE/WinRE and issue: `BootRec /FixMbr && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Windows, GPT disks always boot through UEFI and MBR disks through CSM/BIOS. You have an MBR disk, so I presume you have CSM enabled in UEFI and it's used to boot Windows. This, combined with lack of EFI System Partition (ESP), means that you're effectively booting like BIOSes used to.

This means that to make the drive autonomously bootable for Windows, you have to:

1. Set proper boot order in UEFI.
2. Write Windows MBR to the drive.
3. Write proper VBR (aka boot sector) to the system partition.
4. Ensure `bootmgr` uses that drive's BCD.
5. Update entries in BCD.

Steps 2-5 can be performed using any installation media for Windows 7 or newer. If you don't have one, just [download Windows 10 from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO/) and make a bootable flash disk, either using the tool they provide or with [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) (make sure to select BIOS/CSM boot mode).

Clone your partition first. Then disconnect the old drive (with PC turned off, of course). Boot Windows installation media, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open command prompt.

- To write MBR: `bootrec /fixmbr`
- To write VBR: `bootrec /fixboot`
- To recreate BCD:

  ```
  C:         (or whatever letter got assigned)
  cd boot
  attrib bcd -s -h -r
  rename bcd bcd.old
  bootrec /rebuildbcd
  ```

That should be sufficient to make the new drive autonomously bootable. You can reconnect the old one, check boot priority in UEFI and make sure SSD will boot. Then you can proceed to partitioning the old drive using your brand new clone.

Comment: Ah. So the missing step was to disconnect the old drive and fix the MBR? Thanks, I'll try as soon as I have access to the PC again in a week or so and probably report success. Completely forgot about `/fixmbr`, used that in WinXP times…

Comment: The step with BCD is important too. Currently you have an entry for the old Windows installation on both partitions. Even with correct MBR, `bootmgr` may attempt to load that one.

Comment: What's the BCD?

Comment: [Boot Configuration Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process#Boot_Configuration_Data). ntldr (Win2k/XP bootloader) used `boot.ini`, bootmgr (Vista+ bootloader) uses BCD.

Comment: Ah. I didn't have to deal with boot issues since XP, so thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, my acquaintance already used another solution, so I wasn't able to try yours. Either way, I'll keep it in mind for the next time.